# horizontal alignment of cube

Tags: html, css

To give headings for the cube I wrote text outside the cube with the p tags.

I gave `clear:left` to `p` tag because of it text came down.

other cubes also came down because of it.

how to make the cubes horizontal alignment in one row?

providing my fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/NmPFU/2/

```
<div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png">testing</div>
                        <p style='clear: left; text-align:left;'>rajkumar</p>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/search.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/yourfiles.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/shareFiles.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='/Customer/index/?step=create' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='/Customer/' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/custProfile.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/custQuote.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='/Sales/order/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a href='/Sales/' style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/salesOrders.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/vendorProfile.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/reports.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/yourfiles.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/admin.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/shipLogistic.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/accReceivable.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/custRMA.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/production.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/CRM.png"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: what is your `<p>` tag supposed to be doing here?

Comment: for giving the icon heading i gave p tag

Comment: you really need to clarify your question.  do you want a single heading for all cubes in that section, like http://jsfiddle.net/8CtGE/3/  ?

Comment: each individual cubes should have a text below it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you might want to use a Div to surround that `<p>` tag, have you tried that?

***EDIT***

Here is what I did

1. Removed style `clear:left` from `<p>`
2. added 4 `<br/>` before the `<p>`
3. added a style of `margin-top:100px`  to `

here are the results
personally i think all the code is a little messy it was a little hard to read. but I am spoiled that way.

http://jsfiddle.net/8CtGE/

***EDIT***
in the Fiddle I Moved the `<p>` Tag Above and Outside of the `<div class="melonhtml5_gallery">` tag

the cube that has the word testing on it, is not so much a cube so the spacing is off.
that looks like something that will need to be addressed in the code for the Cubes itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/8CtGE/1/

otherwise it is as you wish now.

***LAST EDIT***

**you really need to clarify your question.**

do you want a single heading for all cubes in that section, like http://jsfiddle.net/8CtGE/3/  ? if this is so you should start with the basics of HTML and CSS before Tackling something as complex as what you are doing with the cubes.  I hope that I am not sounding Rude, but someone needs to tell you that what I have done is **Basic HTML/CSS Editing**

Comment: is that the outcome that you were looking for?  what browser are you using to see the rendered page?

Comment: the search icon should come immediately after the inventory control icon....the first four icon should align in the same line

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle, there is no gap under the very first cube. I think the formatting for this will be found in the actual application or you may need to set up seperate "rows" of cubes for that left side

Comment: i need the first four cubes in the same horizontal line including inventory cube.....

Comment: i should give this as the heading rajkumar for each cube......not for the whole column.....